# Is it possible to have paragraph text as an After Effects template (in Premiere Pro)?

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I have a text layer in After Effects that I'm using as a text template for a Premiere Pro project. Is it possible to make the editable text multi-line, and if so, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to sync our watches: Both **point text** and **paragraph text** have the potential to be either **single** or **multiline**.

If you create multi-line text using so-called **point text** like this (ie, single-click of the Text tool, w/ multiple lines created by hitting the return key) ...

[image]

..then Premiere will display the multiple lines like this:

[image]

On the other hand, if you create multi-line text using so-called **paragraph text** like this (ie, click-drag a rectanglar area with the Text tool, w/ multiple lines created by hitting return key ***or*** word-wrapping) ...

[image]

..then Premiere will display editable fields like this:

[image]

So basically Premiere will add additional editable text fields whenever it sees linebreak characters in your text, whether it's point text or paragraph text. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. After Effects has a setting where the text of text layers can be made editable in Premiere. This only appears to work with point text (I can only edit one line in Premiere). I was wondering if you can add multiple lines.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't even know about that feature, ha. I'm taking a look at it right now.

Comment: Ok, I think I've gotten the hang of the "text template" feature now, and have updated my answer.